# Potentially Dangerous Request.Path Exception From Silverlight Object

Tags: silverlight, validation, path, request

I have a Silverlight object element embedded in a page in the usual way

*<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="500px">
    <param name="source" value="/app/ClientBin/appname.SilverLight.xap" />*

Since upgrading to Silverlight/.NET 4.0 this has been throwing intermittent exceptions

*A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).*

from the colon in the path name - the page url is given as

*http://www ... /data:application/x-silverlight-2,*

I know request validation is now enabled for all requests but why would this embedded object be treated as a separate request? Parts of the jQuery.js file have also shown up as separate requests and causing the same problem

http://www ... /,c.css(this[a],

either ways there is no visible impact on the user.